# Using Countifs in Access 2016 Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am using the following formula in Excel to conditionally rank the ballNumber column:

```
=COUNTIFS(BallByBallTable[matchId],A2,BallByBallTable[batsman],E2,BallByBallTable[ballNumber],"<"&C2)+1
```

It works ok but the table (which is imported from Access) is now quite large and causes Excel to run very slowly.

Is it possible to convert this formula so I can use it in an Access query?

Thanks

Comment: Ranking records in Access is a common topic. Do research, make attempt, and when you have specific issue post question. When you do, post raw data as text table with attempted SQL statement.

Comment: Start with http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html